# Infer schema option for xml processing using databrics spark API

Tags: xml, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have to process a xml which has string values like "0001546". If i load those into dataframes using databrics xml API it's converting actual string value into double type, and there is the issue double is changing my complete value from "0001546" to 1546. This is because of implicit type casting of string to number but i don't want this to behave like that. Expecting actual value should be treated as it is.
One option would be to specify manual schema for xml which not feasible in my case.
I found a bug reported to databrics to disable infer schema like csv files.
Do we have any workaround/solution to solve this? Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an tactical solution to this till the time it get fixed in new release.
I've created a placeholder xml file which is placed into input folder which has all xml files which i want to process.
The id field in placeholder xml file has value like `<Id>x0001546</Id>` please note that one extra 'x' character has been added into dummy record.
Since, by default value of sampling infer schema is 1(no need to do it for every record), spark recognized this field should be treated as alphanumeric. Later on i've filtered out the placeholder xml record from dataframe.

Comment: Hi, did you find any better solution for this?